# Login Flow with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, authentication, stateless

I have a stateless header based authentication API endpoint. I would like to build my website that will be requesting data from it. Being a stateless authentication and given the fact that the server does not maintain any sessions, How would I go about implementing a Login Flow for the same. I am building an AngularJS SPA and would be using multiple routes in my application. What would be the best way to approach the authentication for a production level service. I came across AngularJS cookies, but it is not really that secure(I am concerned about a possible Cookie Hijack). What are my options here? Any help will be really appreciated as I am completely new to login flow.

I will be sending the headers over SSL for obvious reasons. But how prone am I to an attack by doing this? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https There are weaknesses pointed out here, but how do I overcome these? Any help will be really appreciated.

PS: I understand that there are better ways to implement it currently by making modifications on the server side, but if I were considering this current scenario of how everything works(explained above) how would I go about with it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using JSON Web Tokens (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token).... check out https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt for a ready to use solution for Angular. You just need to setup the server side part.

Comment: But if I were considering sticking with not changing the way my server functions due to other dependencies that I will have to end up modifying, how would I go about with this?

Comment: It's not that hard to implement a server side JWT system, actually there are several libraries available for PHP, ASP and others that are pretty easy to set up. All you have to do is create a new end point for your API that handles JWT login and validation, no need to modify your server side app, just connect the JWT system to your db and you're good to go (some tweaking required).